# Mongoose or JavaScript group results into arrays by same field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently looking for the most efficient way of taking results from mongoDB and sorting them into arrays grouped by the same field.

my Schema is as follows

```
var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    description:String,
    location:{lng:Number, lat:Number},  
    date:Date,
    place_id:String,
    ....
});
```

I get all Events into an array called `all_events` and want to group them into arrays by place_id. I have tried this (below) and it works fine, but I was wondering if their is a way to do so in mongoose or a more efficient way to do this in JavaScript.

```
    let included_places = [];
    let places_events=[];

    for(let i=0; i<all_events.length; i++){
        if(included_places.indexOf(all_events[i].place_id)<0) included_places.push(all_events[i].place_id);
    }
    for(let i=0; i<included_places.length; i++){
        let the_events = all_events.filter(a=>a.place_id==included_places[i]);
        places_events[i] = the_events;
    }
```

Comment: You can use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation instead of finding and then using javascript

Comment: Thank you. `$$ROOT` was the important part I couldn't find before, so I had thought `$group` was unusable for me. This worked.

`Event.aggregate([{ $group:{_id:"$place_id", events:{$push:"$$ROOT"}} }])`